# ToExpression from commandline

Tags: latex, linux, display, command-line

I like to use Mathematica 8.0 from the commandline,
then I just have to SSH in, no matter where I am, and go.
I also like to do this without forwarding X, because that is slow and lags on my connection.

I have a wrapper script that adds keyword completion and readline functionality,
and will, iff i have forwarded X start a java program to display the graphs.

However, this issue occurs whether or not I use my wrapper script.

I would like to import some code from LaTeX,

so I do:

```
In[7]:= ToExpression["x=4-2", TeXForm]
```

which outputs:

```
Can't open display "localhost:12.0"
```

then *hangs*.
I'm not sure why it wants to open the display in the first-place. 
**What is going on?**

If I use `StandardForm` this works fine:

```
In[6]:= ToExpression["x=4-2", StandardForm]

Out[6]= 2
```

It appears that people can't reproduce this.
So some more details of my setup.

- I am SSHing using Putty from Windows to Debian Wheezy,
- then SSHing again into Debian Wheezy to ensure there is no Putty related issue (using `ssh -x` (I have tried both with and without this step)
- I execute `.../Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/Executables/math`
- `ToExpression["x=4-2", TeXForm]` and press enter
- the above occurs

I have tried this on both a normal user and the root user.

Other than this mathematica appears to be working fine

Comment: Can you post a minimal example to reproduce this? If I do ssh -x user@localhost and test your examples, it works as expected.

Comment: That is a MWE, it is one line. I have tested it.
It causes the issue for me.


I have edited the question to make it clear that it occurs, for me, even if i am just running the `math` executable directly.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Mathematica 8.0.0.0, neither with nor without X forwarding. In both cases I get `x == 2`.

Comment: Very weird. I have added more details to the question. Perhaps it is enviroment/OS specific... ::puzzled::

Comment: TeXForm conversion is quite complicated.  For a sample run this in the Notebook interface on a fresh kernel: `TracePrint[
 ToExpression["x=4-2", TeXForm],
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]`.  For me (in version 10) this *also* hung after crashing `TeX.exe`.  I think it is possible that an external command (e.g. to `TeX.exe`) attempts an invalid action (display?) and this is what in turn hangs *Mathematica*.

Comment: OK, I now could reproduce the problem, except that for me it tried to connect to ":0.0" (which explains why my previous attempt to reproduce it failed; I tried on a computer where I was also logged in/running X locally, and thus connecting to :0.0 would not fail). Using `strace` reveals that it executes a front end at some time; I guess that's where the problem arises.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug.  It is a well known limitation when running the kernel on a headless server on Linux.  Some operations require the Front End.  Importing TeX is such an operation.  The Front End *requires* an X server, regardless of what it's being used for.

Simple solution: use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) as the X server.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315464/exporting-a-plot-as-an-image-in-mathematica-on-a-machine-without-x11-ie-withou

Comment: `xvfb-run /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/Executables/math` works like a charm.

Comment: I think it is a bug, in the sense that eg `Plot[Sin[x],{x,-5,5}]` doesn't cause mma to hang. So, while I agree that the fact that it fails is not a bug, that it hangs seems to be. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @acl Yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

After managing to reproduce the problem (using Mathematica 8.0.0.0) and looking into an strace I come to the following result:

- After issuing the `ToExpression["x=4-2", TeXForm]`, the kernel start a front end:

  ```
  15166 execve("[...]/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica", ["[...]/SystemFiles/F"..., "-topDirectory", "/misc/psi/math-8.0", "-mathlink", "-server", "-noSplashScreen", "-display", ":0.0", "-linkmode", "connect", "-linkprotocol", "SharedMemory", "-linkname", "7p2_shm"], [/* 57 vars */] <unfinished ...>
  15166 <... execve resumed> )            = 0
  ```

  (note that 15166 here is the process number of the front end process; also note that I shortened irrelevant parts of the path to `[...]`)
  Apparently the functionality of converting TeXForm expressions is part of the front end, not of the kernel, and therefore a front end is started in order to do the conversion. And apparently the front end tries to connect to an X server and fails when this
- The newly started front end tries to connect to X, and fails, giving the message and terminating:

  ```
  15166 write(2, "Can't open display \":0.0\"\n", 26) = 26
  15166 exit_group(-1)                    = ?
  ```
- The kernel apparently is not prepared to the front end terminating at that point and apparently sits in an infinite loop waiting for data from the front end:

  ```
  14914 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1}) = 0 (Timeout)
  14914 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1}) = 0 (Timeout)
  14914 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1}) = 0 (Timeout)
  14914 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1}) = 0 (Timeout)
  14914 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1}) = 0 (Timeout)
  ```

  repeated *many* times, until finally the `SIGINT` arrives from me pressing <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>.

In summary, it seems to me that you have triggered what I assume to be a bug (or rather, two bugs playing together) in Mathematica 8 (I can't check whether it is also in later versions, since version 8 is the latest I have access to):

- The front end started by the kernel tries to connect to the X server and terminates after it fails to connect, although the task it was started for obviously does not need X in any way.
- The kernel apparently cannot cope with the premature termination of the front end